# Iterate over object in state every x seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object of `users` in state, I would like to iterate over it and display a different user every `x` seconds.

This is what I have so far:

```
class DisplayUser extends Component {  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { name: 'batman', age: 25 },
        { name: 'spiderman', age: 27 },
        { name: 'superman', age: 26 }
      ]
    };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      users: prevState.users
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>User: {this.state.users[0].name}</div>;
  }
}
```

Essentially a `for` loop, but I'm finding it difficult to do in react, what should I do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with your current version:

1. That `setState` call won't do anything, as you're not actually changing the state
2. You're always showing the first entry in `users`, and not changing it

I'd store an index in state and then use that in `render`, changes flaged with `***` comment:

```
class DisplayUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { name: 'batman', age: 25 },
        { name: 'spiderman', age: 27 },
        { name: 'superman', age: 26 }
      ],
      currentUserIndex: 0                                      // ***
    };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(({users, currentUserIndex}) => ({            // ***
      currentUserIndex: (currentUserIndex + 1) % users.length  // ***
    }));                                                       // ***
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    const user = this.state.users[this.state.currentUserIndex];
    return <div>User: {user.name}</div>;                       // ***
  }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const {Component} = React;
class DisplayUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { name: 'batman', age: 25 },
        { name: 'spiderman', age: 27 },
        { name: 'superman', age: 26 }
      ],
      currentUserIndex: 0                                      // ***
    };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(({users, currentUserIndex}) => ({            // ***
      currentUserIndex: (currentUserIndex + 1) % users.length  // ***
    }));                                                       // ***
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    const user = this.state.users[this.state.currentUserIndex];
    return <div>User: {user.name}</div>;                       // ***
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DisplayUser />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the % is a brilliant solution, thank you for sharing